# Finding what column is breaking the group - in SQL group by

Tags: sql

I'm pulling a query of events - for example:

```
select event_key, c1, c2, c3 
... 
group by event_key, c1, c2, c3 ...
```

I'm expecting to find only 1 row per event key, but I'm getting several.

Is there a way to find what column is causing the split? (e.g. what column is not the same in all rows of the "event_key"?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you see event_keys more than once, and you select all the `c` columns, wouldn't you be able to see which column has different values by looking at the result set? Keep in mind that without knowing your data, there could be values in one or multiple columns.

Comment: As above the answer should be obvious from the data in the query. You don't show your entire query, do the columns all reside in the same table or are from joined tables etc

Comment: If you want just one row per event_key, don't add other columns to the GROUP BY! Simply do `GROUP BY event_key`.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have thousands of rows and you just don't know how to easily find just those issues.  You could do the following as a rough starting point:

```
SELECT event_key
     , COUNT(DISTINCT c1) AS n1, MIN(c1) AS min_c1, MAX(c1) AS max_c1
     , COUNT(DISTINCT c2) AS n2, MIN(c2) AS min_c2, MAX(c2) AS max_c2
     , COUNT(DISTINCT c3) AS n3, MIN(c3) AS min_c3, MAX(c3) AS max_c3
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY event_key
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c1) > 1
    OR COUNT(DISTINCT c2) > 1
    OR COUNT(DISTINCT c3) > 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather complicated question and Jon's answer does not take `NULL` values into account.  You can use logic like this:

```
select event_key,
       (case when count(distinct c1) <> 1 or count(*) <> count(c1)
             then 'duplicates' else 'all same'
        end) as c1_status,
       (case when count(distinct c2) <> 1 or count(*) <> count(c2)
             then 'duplicates' else 'all same'
        end) as c2_status,
       . . . 
from t
group by event_key;
```

Filtering down to `event_key`s only with duplicates is probably most easily done using a subquery:

```
select *
from (select event_key,
             (case when count(distinct c1) <> 1 or count(*) <> count(c1)
                   then 'duplicates' else 'all same'
              end) as c1_status,
             (case when count(distinct c2) <> 1 or count(*) <> count(c2)
                   then 'duplicates' else 'all same'
              end) as c2_status,
             . . . 
      from t
      group by event_key
     ) t
where 'duplicates' in (c1_status, c2_status, . . . )
```